# Did installing Miniconda destroy Python 2.7 on my Mac?

Tags: python, macos, miniconda

Have I lost Python 2.7 and does Mac OS still need it? If so, how do I fix this?

I'm a longtime Python 3.x user on Mac OS. I wanted to try Miniconda3 to see if I could recommend it to Mac and Windows students (non-CS). Now I when I try `$ type -a python3` I get:

```
python3 is /Applications/miniconda3/bin/python3
python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Try `$ type -a python2` and get:

```
-bash: type: python2: not found
```

Try `$ type -a python` and get:

```
python is /Applications/miniconda3/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

I used the Miniconda 64-bit (.pkg installer) under Python 3.7 here:

https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Comment: Almost certainly, it's still there somewhere. Probably at `/usr/bin/python`. There are many symlinks to different interpreters in `/usr/local/bin/`, try something like `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*` that should also show where those symlinks are pointing.

Comment: So, try `/usr/bin/python -c 'import sys; print sys.version'` and it will print something like `[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]`

Comment: Thank you! Typing $ /usr/bin/python revealed that 2.7 is still there. Whew!!

Answer (score 2):

Type `/usr/bin/python` and:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Okay, it's all good. Thanks, juanpa.arrivillaga!

Comment: Another discovery: After entering - conda deactivate - everything returns to normal. That is, $ python launches Python 2.7.10 and $ python3 launches Python 3.7.2. To get back into conda, type - conda activate